# Azure ARM Template to deploy website with cname and certificate

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-deployment, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to build a custom ARM template that deploys a new resource group (web,sql,redis,storage) that also creates a custom CNAME record in our dnsZone hosted in a different/existing resGroup.  Finally, I'd like to add a certificate binding (wildcard) from our KeyVault also stored in the other resGroup.

It seems there is support for adding a zone in the new resGroup, but can't find example of leveraging existing zone and just adding a CNAME record that points to my new web app.

It also seems there are examples of creating Key Vaults, but not binding a site up to an existing cert in an existing vault in a different resGroup.

This is a very common multi-tenant kind of scenario, sure seems it should be possible in our template, without having to rely on PowerShell or Azure CLI.

Comment: Dns is hosted in azure dnszone.

Comment: Yes - I'm trying to use this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.network/dnszones/cname but not having any luck, as it seems to expect the dnsZone is in the same resource group (or else the properties just documented well enough for me to follow).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap your dnsZone resource with a deployment resource and scope it to another group.

```
{
    "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
    "name": "nestedTemplate",
    "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
    "resourceGroup": %%% resource group name goes here %%%,
    "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "template": {
            "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
            "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
            "parameters": {},
            "variables": {},
            "resources": [
                %%%% dnsZone goes here %%%
            ]
        },
        "parameters": {}
    }
}
```

For the KV, you can use the example from the quickstarts:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/webapp-keyvault-ssl/azuredeploy.json

Comment: Thanks - this was exactly what I needed.  Much appreciated.  Didn't realize you could add a second resource group that way.  A hidden gem!